# Remove rows with only NaN/NA/0 value

Tags: r

I have an output from from `tapply` function with many NaN values

```
with(wushang, tapply(Profit.margin, list(Supplier, Mode.of.operations,Category),mean))
```

The simplified output looks like this

```
[01] Category A

                             [1] Distribution [2] Reseller [4] Joint venture
[00000]                      3.090000e+00           NA                NA
[10005]                                NA           NA                NA
[10008]                                NA           NA                NA
[10009]                                NA           NA                NA
[10011]                                NA           NA                NA
[10012]                                NA           NA                NA
[10013]                                NA           NA                NA
[10017]                                NA           NA                NA
[10018]                                NA           NA                NA
```

[01] Category B

```
                             [1] Distribution [2] Reseller [4] Joint venture
[00000]                      3.090000e+00           NA                NA
[10005]                                NA           NA                NA
[10008]                                NA           NA                NA
[10009]                                NA      4660000e+00            NA
[10011]                                NA           NA                NA
[10012]                                NA           NA                NA
[10013]                                NA           NA                NA
[10017]                                NA           NA                NA
[10018]                                NA           NA                NA
```

so i want to remove those rows which has only NA, NaN or zero values.
So expected output will be

```
[01] Category A

                                 [1] Distribution [2] Reseller [4] Joint venture
    [00000]                      3.090000e+00           0                0

[01] Category B

                                 [1] Distribution [2] Reseller [4] Joint venture
    [00000]                      3.090000e+00           0                0
    [10009]                                 0      4.60000e+00           0
```

How can we do that?
Thanks

Comment: Are these `array` output?

Comment: yes these are output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We loop over the `array` ('ar1') with `MARGIN=3` and subset the array elements using `rowSums`.

```
apply(ar1, 3, function(x) 
       x[(rowSums(!is.na(x))!=0)|(rowSums(x, na.rm=TRUE)!=0),])
```

Or we can do with a single `rowSums` with `na.rm=TRUE`.  If the values are all 0 or all NA, in a row, it will return 0, convert to a logical vector (`!=0`) and subset the rest of the rows.

```
apply(ar1, 3, function(x) x[rowSums(x, na.rm=TRUE)!=0,])
```